# Better handling of WP-CRON server load abuse

Tags: cron, wp-cron, scheduled-posts

There are [multiple](http://lucasrolff.com/why-wp-cron-sucks/) [reports](https://support.krystal.co.uk/entries/23117312-wp-cron-php-consuming-too-much-memory-and-cpu) [on](http://www.boltwebhosting.com/wordpress-optimization/wp-cron-php-how-to-stop-it-from-running-frequently.html) [how](http://dansgalaxy.co.uk/2010/10/03/how-to-disable-wordpress-wp-cron/) [wp-cron](http://blog.imperialearth.com/wordpress/taming-the-wordpress-time-machine-wp-cron/) [is](http://support.ecenica.com/wordpress/fix-high-cpu-load-wordpress/) [a](http://blog.mellowhost.com/how-to-stop-wp-cron-php-from-firing.html) [far](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/disabling-the-wp-cronphp-in-wordpress) [from](http://buildyourblog.net/problems/disable-wp-cron-running-background) ideal solution because it runs every time a page is loaded, which is unnecessary in most scenarios (one scenario in which it would be necessary is when you use *scheduled posts*)

The common advice is to add `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` to wp-config.php then schedule a real cron job (if you have enough admin access to so).

But **as of WP 3.3, there is [WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT](http://wpengineer.com/2382/wordpress-constants-overview/)**, which "*defines a period of time in which only one cronjob will be fired*".

If you run hundreds of WP installs you would have to create (and delete, when that wp install is removed) a LOT of cron jobs, which can become a nuisance. Therefore, it **seems that the best solution these days is setting `define('WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 900);`** (if you want wp-cron to run every 900 seconds).

**The question is: has anyone used WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT with this purpose yet? Is this its intended use?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the intended use of the `WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT` constant.

When WordPress is loaded, it checks to see if a cron job is running (if cron is locked). If cron is not locked, it will try to create a lock - if the lock timeout has not been reached, no lock can be acquired and cron is not run.

If no cron job is running, and the timeout has passed (meaning a lock can be created), then cron is run.

Comment: thanks! and `define('WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 900);` is the correct syntax?

Comment: Yes. Place that definition in `wp-config.php` and keep in mind it's in seconds.

Comment: Didn't work. One site (3.5.1, on the same same as all other sites) which has the Newsletter plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/newsletter/) was able to fire up wp-cron.php 9 times in the last hour (while WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT = 900)

Comment: It surely isn't working... I'm still occasionally (now on other sites than the one above)getting more than 1 hit to wp-cron from localhost within 900 seconds (each with a different ?doing_wp_cron=XXXXXXXXX)

Comment: Be careful how you qualify "fire up wp-cron.php." Just because the file is called doesn't mean cron is running. The check to see whether or not cron jobs should run is *inside* wp-cron.php. Making a request to that file will check the timeout, then either proceed or exit.

Comment: Duh, of course! I guess we are done, thank you. If you can suggest a way to check whether any cronjobs are being run I'd appreciate.